# Perform additional actions upon read or write to filesystem

Tags: python, linux, perl, linux-kernel, filesystems

How can I perform additional shell actions when a file is read or written to a linux mounted filesystem (local or otherwise)?

I'm specifically looking to:

- make database or rpc calls (via bash,perl,python, etc) when specific file extensions are written (known application specific extensions)
- identify the process that read or wrote the file (and identify dependencies for that file if possible)

I seem to remember this being possible with some `LD_` variant (`PRELOAD` etc.) but am unsure on the specifics.

Comment: check the Inotify tools & lib.

Answer (score 1):

pyinotify is exactly what you need: http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/

I've used it in the past as a hacky way to trigger emails whenever a file is downloaded or uploaded via sftp by just monitoring the SFTP log file and parsing the log messages.